# Elliptic Curve Group Cycle At Inflection Point?

Tags: elliptic-curves

The elliptic curve $ y^2 = x^3 -x + b $ has 2 points of inflection where $ y'' = 0 $. Visualized [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=tangent%20to%20y%5E2%20%3D%20x%5E3%20-%20x%20%2B%201%20at%20x%20%3D%200.0871132996248343).

It seems that $ P + P $ for at say the upper point would be $ - P $ since the tangent at $ P $ intersects "triply" at $ P $ and therefore $ P + P + P = 0 $.

If I am correct then it seems that $ 2P = - P $, $ 3P = 0 $, $ 4P = P $, $ 5P = -P $, $ 6P = 0 $, and so forth. This "feels unusual" since no other point except the left-most one does this. All other points seem to bounce around indefinitely when you compute $ nP $.

Is there any special term or treatment in elliptic curves for the point I have described for which $ nP \in \{ O, -P, P \} \forall n $? Or, is my math incorrect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If one has a Weierstrass elliptic curve
$$E:\quad y^2=x^3+ax+b$$
then a nonzero point $P$ satisfies $3P=O$ if and only if $P$
is an inflection point, that is the tangent meets $E$
with multiplicity $3$.

It's not true that every point "bounces around" when you compute $nP$.
Over the complex numbers, an elliptic curve has $n^2$ points with $nP=O$.
Over the real numbers, at least $n$ of them have real coordinates.
These are the *torsion points* of $E$. However Barry Mazur proved that
on a curve with rational cooefficients, any torsion point with rational
coordinates has $nP=O$ with $n\le12$.

Comment: Thanks. That last part was slightly confusing. I guess it leaves open the fact that a curve with rational coefficients does have n points with real coordinates with nP = 0 for all n, but when n > 12 the points will not have rational coordinates?  (+1)

Comment: An elliptic curve with real coefficients has either $n$ or $2n$ real solutions of $nP=O$.